# I have written a javascript code for compiling the solidity code but it's showing error

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc, mocha, solcjs

I was trying to compile my contract using solc compiler but it returning me some errors. I will place my solidity code along with the error that I am getting here. Please help me out to sort this error out asap if possible.

**This is the solidity code that I am using:**

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Maxsupply {
    string public message;
    function Maxsupply(string newMessage) public{
        message = newMessage;
    }
    function setmessage(string _message) public{
        message = _message;
    }
}
```

**This is the code that I have written in javascript for compiling the contract:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','message.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');
console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
```

**Error:**

```
(node:1091) V8:
/Users/saitejakuruva/Documents/Inbox/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:3
Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib
```

Comment: Hi there. What is the `solc` command you're using? (Or what is the Javascript code you've written?) What version of `solc` are you running?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question please go through that once again . I have provided the solidity code and about I'm using 0.4.25 version of solc

Answer (score 0):

Your `node_modules` directory is probably corrupted.  Try removing it and do `npm i` again.  Also try updating `solc` version.

Comment: I have all the stuff you have suggested me but I am unable to sort out this error .